# How can I refer to an ImageButton in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, imagebutton

I have an html page.
There is a div in the body of the html page where I added some buttons and images.

```
<div id="div_one">
<button id="button_one">
<asp:Image id="image_button_one" ImageUrl=".." runat="server">
</button>
</div>
```

Up this div there is a form where I put inside an:

```
<form..>
    <asp:ImageButton id="id_one" runtat="server" ImageUrl=".." visible="false">.
</form>
```

The buttons have a jquery/javascript associated. 
When I click on the button "button_one" for example, there are some css that modify the page and nothing else.

The point is that: when jquery is executed ($("#button_one").click(){..}) I want to visualize the ImageButton and eventually, if there is a click on that, change the page.

Is possible to refer to that ImageButton to visualize it and use it if necessary?How?

Comment: what do you mean by 'visualize it'?

Comment: What does your browser render? Post the HTML your server sends to your browser for the button.

Comment: I put the ImageButton invisible with visible="false"

Comment: Give it a unique class name and tackle this class name using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make its ClientIDMode Static :

```
<form..>
        <asp:ImageButton id="id_one" runtat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl=".." visible="false">.
    </form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#id_one").click(function(){

// do something here

})
```

For Visualizing it:

```
 $("#id_one").show();
```

**UPDATED:**

In Visible = "false" case control is not rendered on Client Side so it's not accessible via client side script, instead of setting visible to do set css property like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="id_one" style="display:none;" runtat="server" ImageUrl=".."
```

visible="true">

Comment: before that I have to visualize it. I tried with $("#id_one").css('visibility', 'visible'); inside $("#button_one").click(){..} but doesn't work.

Comment: we added comment in the same time!:D

Comment: you imagebutton id is different the one you passing is different

Comment: no I just put the wrong answer. it was a mistake, the code is correct.

Comment: If someone click on the button, I want to visualize an ImageButton and use it. So, I use the id of the button to modify css and in this scenario I want the ImageButton that have of course a different id.

Comment: if its id is known then you can do

Comment: how?because $("#id_one").show(); or $("#id_one").css('visibility', 'visible'); inside $("#button_one").click(){}don't work (other code for css of the div inside $("#button_one").click(){} works!).

Comment: you have set Visible property false on server side?

Comment: $("#id_one").click(function(){} works but before that I have to visualize the button "id_one". The code to visualize doesn't work I'm sure about that!

Comment: It is in the form I wrote, runat=server and visible="false"

Comment: runat="server" is required

Comment: see updated answer you have to do it via css inline, because visible false not renders the control on page so it is not accessible obviously via client side script

Comment: Interesting.. I'll try tomorrow and I'll let you know!

Comment: yes!the problem was that I used visible in server side, instead setting visible and hidden with css make it works!Thank you very much!

Comment: glad that it helped out